# Updating data in react with graphQl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

So I have a react component with input select, which is located in my header:

```
import { useState } from "react";
function ChangeCurrency(){
   const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState("USD");
   function changeSelectValue(event) {
     setSelectValue(event.target.value);
     }
    return (
      <select
        name="currencies"
        id="currencies"
        className={classes.changeCurrency}
        value={selectValue}
        onChange={changeSelectValue}
      >
        <option value="USD">$USD</option>
        <option value="GBP">£GBP</option>
        <option value="AUD">A$AUD</option>
        <option value="JPY">¥JPY</option>
        <option value="RUB">₽RUB</option>
      </select>
    );
}
```

and another component with products, which is in main content:

```
import Products from "./Products";
import {
  useQuery,
  gql,
} from "@apollo/client";
function ProductsAll(){
const GET_PRODUCTS = gql`
  query {
    category(input: { title: "all" }) {
      name
      products {
        id
        name
        gallery
       prices {
          currency {
            label
            symbol
          }
          amount
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
      const{loading,error,data} = useQuery(GET_PRODUCTS)
      if(loading){
          return <div>loading...</div>
      }
      if(error){
          return<div>error..</div>
      }
      return (
        <Products data={data}/>
      );
    }
    export default ProductsAll;
```

I have a few categories so doing everything in one app.js isn`t an option(
how can I update data of second element with select changing?

Comment: It's not quite clear how the second element would depend on the selected value, i.e. what data you want to update how. Also where does "*I have a few categories*" come into play? What would be different if you had only one category, how could you "*do everything in one app.js*"?

Comment: So if i could do everything in one i would just generate data every time the state changes. The select answers for which currency of product will be shown. I have all, tech and clothes categories which are generated in components in routes as Link navigates to. If i change currency and go to another category it will work but i need to render the products immediately on the page. I hope I explained it right ^-^

Comment: App.js:
navigation: routes: all tech clothes

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*generate data*". Your `data` isn't generated, it's the result of a constant graphql query (not depending on any other variables).

Comment: By generating I mean getting needed data and creating html for it. I have different currencies and I need to show the only one which is selected

Comment: But you haven't shown any of the code for that. Is it hidden in your `<Products data={data}/>` component?

Comment: yes,  {data.category.products.map((product) => {
          return <ProductCard data={product} key={product.id} />;
        })}

Comment: Prices in product card(const currencies = document.getElementById("currencies");
const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState(currencies.value)):
         {data.prices.map((price) => {
           if (price.currency.label === selectValue) {
             return (
               <div key={"price" + data.id} id={"price" + data.id}>
                 {price.amount + price.currency.symbol}
               </div>
             );
           } else {
             return null;
           }
         }

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that code with proper formatting, don't post it in a comment

Comment: "*`const currencies = document.getElementById("currencies"); const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState(currencies.value);`*" - ah, well, don't do that. [Lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), and provide it from a context or pass it down explicitly.